# Extjs multiple representations of data

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a Rest endpoint, that sends and receives objects of the form

```
[
    {id: 1, Name: "Type"},
    {id: 2, Name: "Type:Subtype"},
    ...
]
```

I want to display this in an editable tree, using Sencha Extjs 6. I am confused as to where and when to transform the data, and how to keep changes synchronized without side effects. My current (not nice) method is to reload the data and then reset the tree's store using the converted values, but that collapses all of the expanded nodes

- I can get and save entries using a model and a store
- I can convert the data into a form suitable for use in a treepanel
- I do not know the "right" way to do so, and to have changes in either store reflected in the other.

For clarity, the converted tree store has a data stucture:

```
[
    {
        text: "Type",
        children: [
            {
                text: "Subtype",
                isLeaf: true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with the answer: a save button.

Bound the Load event of the Rest Store to the controller, and in that method copied the values into the TreeStore.

Edits are made to the TreeStore - kept purely client side

Save button copies new data back into Rest Store and calls sync(). Easy to follow. Code is kept mostly declarative. And I can provide default values in the VM's data field. Easy to do - shame it's not made clear in the documentation somewhere